# How can I have the informations from 2 differents columns represented as 1 in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, merge, pivot-table

In my data, I have 2 columns who represent a country visited before and a country visited after the cities that I am studying.

Here's a picture of my data sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dam55.png

I'd like to represent in my pivot table all the countries linked to each city (so before and after the city). I'd like to have the cities in my line and all the countries who can possibly be visited before and after as my columns and the count of those in my values.

Here is a picture of what I'd like to achieve, but I can only do it for one of the columns (country after in that case). I'd like the same format but having the data of both before and after (but it's important to know that it's not necessarily the same countries in the 2 columns so I can't just have one of the country columns as the head and both as the values): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gULz.png

When I place the cities in the line and the 2 country columns in value and columns, it is so difficult to read the table as the before and after are all separate and might even be counted as a pair. and if they are not in the pivot table column they only give me the count of countries before and after but not by the countries, which is not what I'm looking for.

Here is a picture of the result of the pivot table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8S4n.png

I also tried to create a new field by doing «Country before» + «Country after» but it doesn't seem to work as the data is in text.

Comment: Can you add an image/table of your preferred output as that will affect the best solution

Comment: I just added the output I'd like to have as the second image. Is it helping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think understand the output now. You essentially want a count of the number of occurrences of each country in columns B+C, grouped by the city. I'll provide a few ways so you can select what suits you best.

**Simplest method**

The easiest way I can think of is simply paste the second column under the first column and then pivot on this new table.

**COUNTIF**

A more repeatable way would be to essentially make your own pivot table and use the `COUNTIF` function to count the instances of each country.

`=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,$F2,$B$1:$B$6,G$1)+COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$6,$F2,$C$1:$C$6,G$1)`

**Power Query**

The most repeatable way is to use PowerQuery. This will enable you to refresh the data at the click of a button. To do this (assuming you have excel 2016) go to the Data  tab and, with you data selected click "From Table/Range". The Power Query window will open. On the top left of the screen will be a button with advanced editor. When you open it you'll see the following code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"City", type text}, {"Country Before", type text}, {"Country After", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Replace the code with the following code. Note that your table may be called something different. You can see what it's called on the second line of the code. The code below uses "Table1" - you can replace this with the name of your table.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"City", type text}, {"Country Before", type text}, {"Country After", type text}}),
    #"Before" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Country Before"}),
    #"After" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Country After"}),
    #"Append" = Table.Combine({#"Before",#"After"}),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(Append, "Country", each Text.Combine({[Country After], [Country Before]}, ""), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"Country After", "Country Before"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with the arrangement of these fields is that the columns are a lot wider than needed giving me the total for before and for after. what I'm trying to get is having the result of before+after as the column head and the values of both in the table. Would it be easier to try and merge 2 pivot table (1 of before and 1 of after) or is there a way to get that result directly with just 1 pivot table?

Comment: Can you make an example of the desired output not in a pivot table (e.g. just type what you would like to see where) - I'm having trouble understanding how you can have fewer columns when you have such an array of possible combinations (any country with any country).

Comment: if you look at the data sample (1st pic), for all the Baie Comeau in the A column, I want to see the total of time Canada will appear in the column B and C (7). so in my pivot table for the combination of the line Baie Comeau and the column Canada would appear 7. For the line Duluth and the Column USA it would be 6. I'm really sorry, it seems like I have some trouble explaining well what I want. is it more clear?

Comment: For every city in column A, I want to see the number of occurences of every Country from Column B and C combined.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a few different solutions